# Identify this series: genetically modified animals, indistinguishable from humans, as soldiers and servants

Tags: story-identification

1960's series involving genetically modified animals to serve as soldiers and servants.  They were indistinguishable from humans except for a mandated mark on the palm of the hands.   The author (who I can't recall) was fairly well known at the time.

Comment: Was this a book series? Cartoon series? Live Action?

Comment: Was this a U.S. series? U.K.?

Comment: Please take a look at the list of questions at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and see how many answer to them you can edit into your question. :)

Comment: Does [The Moreau](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41386-moreau) series by S. Andrew Swann (aka Steven Swiniarski) ring a bell? If so, this question is a duplicate of [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85601/4495).

Comment: Eh, it's a good guess (and I'd upvote it if posted as an answer), but the Moreaus are obviously bestial as far as I recall.

Comment: Sort of like Cordwainer Smith's [Instrumentality of Mankind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentality_of_Mankind) series, but I don't recall Smith's "underpeople" having marks on the palms of their hands.

Comment: They looked indistinguishable from humans?  Not humanoid with animal characteristics?  IDK, it just seems weird to me and much harder to genetically modify animals to look exactly like humans rather than modify humans to have whatever benefits of the animals (I preseme enhanced strength/speed/senses).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brian Stableford's *Dies Irae Trilogy*
*[The Days of Glory](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8840434-days-of-glory)*, (Ace 1971)

> Ten millennia had passed since the creation of the Beasts, and those ten thousand years had obliterated the original purpose of Adam December and the construct surgeons.
>
> Ten millennia had passed since the word WAR was forgotten and remembered; and that word wiped out ten thousand years of peaceful coexistence.
>
> Ten millennia, one thousand decades, ten thousand years .. and for the first time Humans and Beasts were dying throughout the galaxy.
>
> But it should have been expected: man had created the Beasts in his own image, and unfortunately, the Beasts were just like him.
>
> The first of the brilliant science fiction trilogy of the Dies Irae, by the talented author of CRADLE OF THE SUN

The other two books in the trilogy are:

- *In the Kingdom of the Beasts*, (Ace 1971)
- *Day of Wrath*, (Ace 1971)

Check out the other covers and see if they look familiar.

[image: The Days of Glory]

Comment: If the Beasts had mandatory marks on the palms of their hands, please include something about that, since that seems to be what distinguishes the story we're looking for from a hundred other stories about Beast-men.

Comment: Regarding the marks on their hands, it's been 45 years since I read the books and I no longer own them so I can't confirm that. I do seem to remember that they had identifying marks somewhere since otherwise they looked just like humans (in spite of what the book covers would suggest). I can root around some more on the web to see what I can find.

Comment: While it doesn't specify the hands, this quote from a Stableford fan site review, "To solve this problem Adam December creates 'the beasts' , who are identical to men except they carry the 'Crux Ansata' and have no compunction against breeding." suggests a mark (the 'Crux Ansata' or handled-cross/ankh symbol) and the 'identical to men' part.

Comment: Not to be confused with the standalone novel "Deus Irae" by PKD and Zelazny :)