# Cyberpunk novel, main character is gene-spliced cat person

Tags: story-identification, novel, cyberpunk

This has been bothering me for years. The first cyberpunk I ever read. Main character was genetically modified with cat attributes, and ran with a small crew of other cat people (one was his surrogate son, the other his longtime teammate with panther genes). He was pulled into a scheme with an evil corporation hunting a cybernetic implant that would allow anyone photographic/recorded memory by using the code word "White Rabbit".

I remember there was an evil mayor character named Hatter who was spliced with a lion. At the end of the story the main character essentially took over for Hatter, and looked back on his life filled with regret (it was a downer).

Comment: I would swear we had another query for people gene-spliced with cats recently, but I'm having no luck finding it.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Are you thinking of the Moreau series? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85601/101407

Comment: Ah, could be. I found a few other semi-matches involving feline spliced protagonists, but not enough matching points.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I checked those books out, and they don't match any of the points _except_ gene-spliced felinoids.  I haven't found any good partial matches either.