# Looking for noir-ish sci-fi "story"set on Mars, read in past decade but

Tags: story-identification

...but this one is pretty vague, for me, I apologize in advance.

All I remember is the following:

- Read it on a tablet, very possibly via kindle or whatever Apple's version of that was
- Could have been short story, novel, novella... anything. I don't think I finished it but I DO feel like it was part of a series.
- Male protagonist was a cop or P.I. maybe had some sort of military background or even just partisan combat experience
- Protagonist had a "frenemy" of sorts, maybe on the opposite side of the law or conflict who didn't seem to understand they weren't actually friends for some reason, maybe shared history?
- Possible tiger based genetic modifications somewhere in the story?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The noir on Mars reminded me of Red Planet Blues by Robert J. Sawyer.

Answer (score 6):

Except for the tiger gene mods, this sounds very much like *The Last Campaign* by Martin L. Shoemaker, book 2 of the Near Earth Mysteries.

This is available on Kindle (that's where I've read his work).
Protagonist is a "retired" space admiral, married to a retired captain who was most recently in command of an Aldrin cycler (transport from Earth to Mars and back) called *Aldrin City* (that story is in *The Last Dance*, book 1), and the characters appear in a number of Shoemaker's other stories and novels as well.

In *The Last Campaign* the husband, Nicolau Aames, had an acquaintance who (in his opinion) had gotten what was coming to him and now lived in a powered exoskeleton to be able to stand and walk even in Mars 38% gravity, and who for some reason considered Nicolau a friend.

It's a murder mystery, set in the civilian portion of the first large city on Mars; plenty of darkness, with POV mainly that of the retired admiral, Rosalia Morais.  It's heavily laced with Brazilian food, music, and culture; native to Rosalia and adopted long hence by Nicolau.  And behind the initial murder is a greater conspiracy that could threaten the very future of civilian occupation of Mars.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the *[Moreau](https://www.goodreads.com/series/41386-moreau)* series by S. Andrew Swann as per the unaccepted answer to [Book series about a future where gene-modified sentient animals were used as soldiers and are trying to find a place in post-war human society](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85601/23243). Summary from the first book, *[Forests of the Night](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/411112.Forests_of_the_Night)*

> Set in Cleveland 100 years in the future, this debut novel is the story of Nohar Rajasthan, Private Eye, who's a moreau--descended from genetically manipulated tiger stock. When Nohar is hired by a being illegally created from human stock to look into a murder, he finds himself caught up in a conspiracy of awesome proportions.

Obviously, one departure is that this first book is not set on Mars.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a long shot, but this question got me scrolling through my library email history until I found:

[Thin Air by Richard Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_Air_(Morgan_novel))

Set on Mars. Military background. Beyond that, I don't know.